How to add an absolute folder in "workbench.editor.customLabels.patterns" (vscode)
I want to add a custom label in the VScode tabs with its new feature "workbench.editor.customLabels.patterns", when I use relative paths it works fine

but I want to refer to an absolute path that the other folder is in another directory outside the Workspace but I can't make this work, someone who can help me

my setting.code-workspace
"workbench.editor.customLabels.patterns": {
  "minibot/*": "${filename}.${extname} / lenin",
  "C:/laragon/www/botnew/my-orignal-bot/*": "${filename}.${extname} / wale"
},

